# C++ Virtual destructors used only when there are virtual functions

Tags: design, object-oriented, c++, constructors

This is from Effective C++ (Meyers):

> Classes not designed to be base classes or not designed to be used polymorphically should not declare virtual destructors

I don't understand why non-polymorphic classes should not declare virtual destructors.

Assuming I have a parent class and a child class, with no virtual functions, and I have a parent-class-pointer to a child object: if I call delete on the parent-class-pointer, it will only call the parent destructor, even though I also want to call the child destructor.

Comment: *"if I call delete on the parent-class-pointer, it will only call the parent destructor, even though I also want to call the child destructor."* - Yeah that practically *is* using the class polymorphically then, so given the above rule it actually *should* have a virtual destructor. Everything fine then.

Comment: "I have a parent class and a child class, with no virtual functions, and I have a parent-class-pointer to a child object" - But why would you want that? The only thing you could do with such a thing is destroy it (or use dynamic_cast).

Comment: @SebastianRedl Or `typeid`!

Answer (score 5):

The keyword here is **not designed**

> Classes **not designed** to be base classes or **not designed** to be used polymorphically

Virtual functions/destructors are not free: they cause performance overhead so you may not want to use them in all cases. However, deleting a derived class object using a pointer to a base class that has a non-virtual destructor results in undefined behavior:

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-37/

So that's the trade off between performance and safety.

Answer (score 5):

> Assuming I have a parent class and a child class, with no virtual functions, and I have a parent-class-pointer to a child object

Then you are using it polymorphically.

Though I don't see much point in doing that. Without virtual members, the subclass does not have much opportunity to affect the program behaviour compared to using just the base class.

A non-polymorphic class is one that will *not* be used to point to objects of derived classes. These are either classes that won't be derived (which in C++ is vast majority!) or classes that are used as base for purpose of code reuse without providing complete interface for anything (e.g. [`std::iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator); it is a public base class of most iterators, but it makes no sense to create a `std::iterator *`).

Answer (score 1):

As a concrete example, assume something like this:

```
class Base
{
    ...
    int some_int;
};

class Derived: public Base
{
    ...
    vector<int> some_vec; // the presence of this field makes `Derived` 
                          // no longer trivially destructible.
};
```

Now if we do this (either directly as shown or indirectly through a smart pointer, e.g.):

```
Base* base = new Derived;
...
delete base;
```

... then `some_vec` will not be destroyed unless `Base` defines a virtual destructor. After all, given only a base pointer, the system lacks the information at runtime to know anything about `Derived` unless there's a virtual table that points to its functions, allowing a dynamic dispatch to occur to get to information/functionality specific to `Derived` like its specific requirements for proper destruction.

To delete an object through a base pointer *is* polymorphic behavior, and to do it safely and correctly without running into undefined behavior requires the base class to define a virtual destructor.

The question ultimately boils down to whether you want to delete objects through a base pointer. If you do, then define a public virtual destructor:

```
class BaseSafeDelete
{
public:
    // Provides safe destruction through a base pointer.
    virtual ~BaseSafeDelete() {}
};
```

If not, define a protected nonvirtual destructor:

```
class BaseNoDelete
{
protected:
    // Prevents deleting outright through a base pointer.
    /*nonvirtual*/ ~BaseNoDelete() {}
};
```

And most importantly, inheritance is something to be designed and decided upfront when designing a base class. It's not suitable as an afterthought to take a class which was not designed for inheritance whatsoever (lacking either a protected nonvirtual dtor or a public virtual dtor as a first sign) and attempt to extend it. For that, see the [Composite Reuse Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).